# img-responsive not reducing the size of image in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have been searching for this answer to img-responsive not reducing the size of image. I have tried all answers I have found here and yet it still does not seem to work. 
You can find the image I am referring to at http://janeanesanborn.com/mission.htm

Here is the code:

```
   <div class="container content"> 
      <div class="row"><!--Row 3-->   
      <div class="col-lg-3 center">
    <img src="assets/img/father-and-baby250.jpg" class="img-thumbnail"></div>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thank you Thomas for taking a look. I would like it to get smaller for the mobile version. Should I use a media queries with a smaller image to swap out or should I call to a smaller column? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The code seems to be working fine on the site you linked to. It is already a small image to begin with so it is hard to tell that it gets smaller as the screen does although it is still noticeable.

You can use `img-thumbnail` or `img-responsive`. Thumbnail will give the image a white border, rounded corners, aswell as some other things where as img-responsive will just make the image responsive.

Either of the ways you mentioned regarding making the image smaller should work fine. You could also start with a smaller image to begin with. Just experiment with them and see which one works best for your specific situation.